# Directional derivative and derivative of $f\left(\boldsymbol{X}\right)=\left\langle \boldsymbol{A},\log\left(\boldsymbol{X}\right)\right\rangle$

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Where:

- $\boldsymbol{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$.
- The function $\log \left( \cdot \right)$ is the element wise $\log$ function: $\boldsymbol{M} = \log \left( \boldsymbol{X} \right) \implies \boldsymbol{M} \left[ i, j \right] = \log \left( \boldsymbol{X} \left[ i, j\right] \right)$.

Is there a way to solve it by first solve the directional derivative and then derive the derivative?
using:

$\nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{X}\right)\left[H\right]=\left\langle \boldsymbol{\nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{X}\right)},\boldsymbol{H}\right\rangle $

And using more elegant way to solve it, without "manually" calculating the derivative, the way I solved it here?:

$f\left(\boldsymbol{X}\right)=\left\langle \boldsymbol{A},\log\left(\boldsymbol{X}\right)\right\rangle =Tr(A^{T}\log\left(\boldsymbol{X}\right))=\sum_{i=1}^{d}\sum_{j=1}^{d}a_{ij}log(x_{ij})$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i_{0}j_{0}}}=\frac{a_{i_{0}j_{0}}}{x_{i_{0}j_{0}}}\Longrightarrow\nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{X}\right)=A\circ Z$

Where $Z=\{Z\in\mathbb{R}^{dxd}|z_{ij}=\frac{1}{x_{ij}}\}$ and $\circ$ denotes element-wise multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(\oslash)$ denote elementwise/Hadamard division and, as an alternative to the bra-ket notation, use $(:)$ to denote the matrix inner product
$$A:B = \langle A,B\rangle$$
Then a summation-free derivation looks like
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\p{\partial} \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
f &= A:\log(X) \\
df &= A:d\log(X) = A:\LR{dX\oslash X}  = \LR{A\oslash X}:dX \\
\grad{f}{X} &= {A\oslash X} \\
}$$
where $df$ is the directional derivative (in the $dX$ direction).

You can also interpret $(df,dX)$ as *differentials*.